# Does Search Sources in Chrome work?

Tags: google-chrome, search

I have a web app that has about 20 js files that are loading. I tried using Ctrl Shift F (Search Sources) to search for function names across all of the source (js) files. But when I search for `myFunction` using the Search Sources feature, it doesn't find anything (`No matches found.`). If I open the source file that contains `myFunction` and use Ctrl F to search, it is found right away. Opening the file containing `myFunction` before using Search Sources doesn't change anything.

It makes me think that Search Sources doesn't actually do what it says or I have to configure it to search js files, which seems odd.

Chrome 30.0.1599.114
Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: Hmm, I tried it and it worked fine. Have you changed any settings? Click the gear-icon in the bottom-right; is `Search in content scripts` check in the *General* tab? Also, are the dev-tools docked?

Comment: Good suggestions (Search in was not checked) but they didn't change the results.

Comment: Huh, it looks like checking "Search in" and closing the tab then reopening fixed it. Make an answer that says that and I'll confirm it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that the `Search in content scripts` settings is checked. It could be that you had cleared it at some point in the past and forgotten to re-set it, or perhaps an upgrade to Chrome modified the setting (I can’t find any confirmation that it currently defaults to off, but others seem to have had it un-checked without realizing it).

1. Click the gear-icon in the developer tools to open dev-tools settings
2. Check `Search in content scripts`
3. Close the tab, re-open it, re-open the dev-tools

[image: Screenshot of search-in-content setting in dev-tools settings]

Comment: That's what I'm doing.

Comment: Oops, I saw the second hotkey.